# MPI Fortran order of operations (division)

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have an MPI code in which I have to loop over matrices. 
The data represents a 3D domain, but it's saved in a 1D array. The decomposition is done in the following fashion:

Suppose `dims = (/2,2,1/)`. 
Number of datapoints in `I`,`,J`,`K` direction:
`NI = 10`, `NJ=10`, `NK=10`. Then the decomposition would split the domain equally in only the `I` and `J` direction:
First domain:

`NI = 5 + 2` (2 extra cells for boundary information from neighbor)

`NJ = 5 + 2` ( same here )

Second domain:

`NI = 2 + 5` (Now the extra boundary cells are in front of the 5 datapoints which represent data belonging to this domain)

`NJ = 2 + 5`

Now for the loop:

```
U_loop_K : DO K=SK_P,EK_P
  LKK=LK_P(K) 
  U_loop_I : DO I=SI_P,EI_P
    LIK=LKK+LI_P(I) 
    U_loop_J : DO J=SJ_P,EJ_P
      INP=LIK+J 
      AP(INP)=AE(INP)+AW(INP)+AN(INP)+AS(INP)+AT(INP)+AB(INP)+AP(INP) 
      AP(INP)=AP(INP)*URFRS
      SU(INP)=SU(INP)+URFMS*AP(INP)*U(INP)
      APU(INP)=1./(AP(INP)+SMALL)
    END DO U_loop_J
  END DO U_loop_I
END DO U_loop_K
```

I'm doing a multi-directional domain decomposition. The `SK_P` and `EK_P` are the starting and ending indices in the `K` direction respectively. The `I` and `J` are done in a similar manner. 
If I decompose the data and execute this code, a small error will start to exist in the `APU` variable, and only that variable.
How does this happen? Is there a round-off error I'm not aware of which is changed by splitting up the do-loops?

I have checked the values of the 'input arrays' so to speak (`AE`, `AW`, etc.) and they are all exactly the same with or without MPI. The first and only difference starts to exist when using the division: `APU(INP)=1./(AP(INP)+SMALL)`.

The variables are all of the `real` type.

Comment: You will have to show us your MPI code and the decomposition. See [mcve].

Comment: The code is really quite elaborate. I'm not sure in what detail I should go. I'll try to adhere to the guidelines laid out in your link and update the question.

Comment: You also need to quantify *a small error* for us.  I expect that you know that floating-point arithmetic is not strictly associative, so the order of operations does have an impact.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark One of the ways I use to test if the arrays are equal is to gather all the data back into one large array (similar to how it would be without MPI) and take the sum of this value.  The array I'm testing this on has a length of: 1381250. And the sum without MPI is: 1.58107085E+10, with the (2,2,1) decomposition the sum is: 1.58077041E+10.  So the difference is: 0.00030044E+10, which is a small 0.02% difference in the _total sum_ .

Comment: @VladimirF Is this enough information? Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I think we need the code.

Comment: Hmmm, on the one hand that difference is rather larger than a glib, hand-waving *Oh, that's down to the non-associativity of f-p arithmetic* sort of explanation explains.  On the other hand in a lot of computational science work neither the algorithms nor the accuracy of the input datasets warrant conclusions beyond the 2nd or 3rd sf anyway.  And your checking technique adds another source of error, ..., best do as @VladimirF advises and show us some code.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I was trying to reimplement the code in a smaller file so I could share it with you. But I was just unable to reproduce the error in that way. It was also very difficult to share the code as it is because it's about 14k+ lines and it would be very difficult to strip away what wasn't needed. But in the process of going over the code I found out the `AP` array actually wasn't exactly the same! The `AP` array was modified when implementing obstacle boundary conditions and something went wrong in the decomposition. Thank you again for helping me find the culprit.